# I want to convert the simple SQL query to mongo query

Tags: mysql, mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

1. Query:

```
Select quiz_name, qty, count, report FROM quizzes INNER JOIN reports ON quizzes.id=reports.quiz_id  WHERE reports.report IS NOT NULL
```

2. Query:

```
Select username,question,report_desc FROM reports INNER JOIN question ON reports.questoion_id quesitons.id INNER JOIN users ON reports.user_id = users.id INNER JOIN quizzes ON reports.quiz_id=quizzes.id Where quizzes.id = 123
```

The thing is I don't know how to apply aggregation lookup with exists and how to lookup into 3rd level with the existed field is true,

Comment: Add sample collection documents from quizzes, questions and reports

Comment: You can try using this [SQL to MongoDB Aggregation Mapping Chart](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) for converting the query.